# Averiguar elementos repetidos en una lista

Tags: java

Tengo una `LinkedList` en java y me gustaría ir almacenando en otro contenedor los elementos que se encuentran repetidos en el contenedor, **¿Cómo lo podría averiguar? ¿Alguna pista?**

```
public Set<Cancion> dameCancionesRepetidas(){
    SortedSet<Cancion> canciones = new TreeSet <Cancion>();
    /**CODIGO*/
    return canciones;
}
```

Tengo un contenedor que supongamos tiene Cancion1, Cancion1, Cancion3, Cancion4, Cancion4.

Pues yo quiero otro contenedor que me devuelva Cancion1, Cancion4, porque son las únicas que están repetidas. Nose si me explico bien

Comment: ¿Puedes acompañar tu pregunta de un ejemplo concreto con código? Esto ayudará a no malinterpretar la pregunta.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado

Comment: ¿Donde está el `LinkedList` en tu ejemplo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se puede hacer usando el Streams API:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedList<String> canciones = new LinkedList<>();
    canciones.add("cancion1");
    canciones.add("cancion1");
    canciones.add("cancion3");
    canciones.add("cancion4");
    canciones.add("cancion4");

    List<String> duplicateList = 
        canciones
            .stream()
            // agrupar por cancion.
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            // filtrar por los que tienen mas de una cancion por grupo
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(String cancion : duplicateList) {
        System.out.println(cancion);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> cancion4
>   cancion1

[**Demostración en vivo**](http://rextester.com/XZKQB68690).

La parte clave del código es:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
```

... que agrupa los elementos por canción, y:

```
.filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
```

... que filtra los resultados a las agrupaciones que tienen más de un elemento, o sea, las que tienen canciones repetidas.

Pueda que tengas que adpatar el código un poquito para tu clase `Cancion`, pero la idea general debería funcionar bien.

Comment: Tiene buena pinta, me podrias explicar que hace .stream() y entrySet() es que por Internet no me queda claro y no habia visto nunca eso, gracias :)

Comment: Y se podria usar algo asi?: `for(Album i : biblioteca){ for(Cancion j : i){...`

Comment: [`.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) es la manera de tomar una lista y acceder a una variedad de métodos que te permiten manipular dicha lista de una manera funcional. Es algo nuevo desde Java 8, y es un tema muy amplio. Te dejo un enlace si quieres leer mas: [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html). [`.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) no es nuevo, es la manera de pasar un `Map` a una lista de elementos.

Comment: En cuanto a tu segundo comentario, no puedo decir porque no lo entiendo. El código no tiene contexto.

Comment: Es que no me dejaba poner bien el codigo, mira si no tienes mucho que hacer podrias ayudarme con un programa en Java? Es que lo tengo casi me faltan 2 metodos pero no se como continuar, mandame un correo: juanma97@outlook.com gracias :)

Comment: Por legibilidad de codigo se pueden mejorar un par de lineas:
`s -> s` por `Function.identity()` y `e -> e.getKey()` por `Map.Entry::getKey`

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciona esta solución:

```
//Lista que contienes las canciones
LinkedList<Object> lista = new LinkedList<>();

//Paso Strings para no enrollarme, pero funciona para cualquier Object
String obj1 = "Cancion1";
String obj2 = "Cancion2";
String obj3 = "Cancion3";

//Cargo la lista repitiendo 2
lista.add(obj1);
lista.add(obj2);
lista.add(obj2);  //REPETIDA 2ª VEZ
lista.add(obj3);
lista.add(obj2);  //REPETIDA 3ª VEZ
lista.add(obj3);  //REPETIDA 2ª VEZ

//Set para las repetidas - EMPIEZA EL BLOQUE QUE NECESITAS
Set<Object> cancionesRepetidas = new HashSet<Object>();
for(Object o : lista){
    //Si no coincide el primer y último index => están repetidas
    if(lista.indexOf(o) != lista.lastIndexOf(o))
        cancionesRepetidas.add(o);
}

System.out.println(cancionesRepetidas);
```

La salida que obtengo es:

> [Cancion2, Cancion3]

NOTA: Si usas un `HashSet` no te dará problemas con que no es comparable que es lo que te pasará si usas un `SortedSet` y no implementas la interfaz